# EmguCV Camera Calibration does not exist

Tags: c#, emgucv, camera-calibration

I'm currently working on a License Plate reader.
I started by using IronOCR, but it's only able to read license plates, when they are taken straight on, and very clear. So I'm giving Emgu a try.

However, when I follow the "License Plate Recognintion in CSharp" on EMGU's wiki, they use CameraCalibration. And I get the error "The name 'CameraCalibration' does not exist in the current context".

I'm using Emgu.CV version 4.7.0.5276.